# How To Separate Objects In Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

I have an app called 'Product' with the following models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to have two separate sections in Django Admin: **Products** and **Featured Products**, depending if `featured = True` or `False`. 
So by default all products are listed under the **Products** section. But if `featured = True` they will be moved to **Featured Products** section. Can you please help me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Write a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for model `Product`.
2. Change the [default manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/) to only returns featured products.
3. Register your proxy model in the admin like any other model.

You can read more about it here: [Using Proxy Models to Customize the Django Admin](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/using-proxy-models-customize-django-admin/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Is there a way to "remove" the product from the **Products** section, once it has been moved to **Featured Products**?

Comment: Yes, read about ModelAdmin.get_queryset method, and filter there the products you want to show. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The simplest perhaps is to create a database view, and then encapsulate it using a django model. You can create a view like so in your database console:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
  SELECT columns
  FROM tables
  [WHERE conditions];
```

Once you have done that, you can reference the view in django like so:

```py
class FeaturedProduct(modes.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '<name of your view here>'
```

Make sure that `managed` is set to `False`. Here is the relevant [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed) for that. You want to do that because django is not creating this model for you, but rather you are creating it yourself.

Another way to do this would be to create a custom `Manager`. These managers allow you to modify the `objects` attribute of your model, allowing you to set a queryset that you want. I think you'd want to take a look at the [Manager documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#managers) and you can take a look at [defining custom querysets for your objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).